# How to run a function in React when the Escape button has been pressed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The whole idea of the component is that the first time the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key is pressed, the value `confirm` in state changes to `true` to verify that the user really wants to execute the `secPress()` function and pressing the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key again within 5 seconds run the `secPress()` function.

Unfortunately, the `secPress()` function in the component never run.

How to get the function to run after the second key press?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export function useKeypress(key, action) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function onKeyup(e) {
      if (e.key === key) action();
    }
    window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyup);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keyup", onKeyup);
  }, []);
}

const App = () => {
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);

  // this function never run
  const secPress = () => {
    console.log("Double escape pressed");
  };

  const _confirm = useCallback(() => {
    setConfirm((prev) => !prev);
    console.log(confirm); // <-- always show false
    if (confirm) {
      secPress();
    }
  }, [confirm]);

  useKeypress("Escape", _confirm);

  useEffect(() => {
    const d = setTimeout(() => {
      setConfirm(false);
    }, 5000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(d);
    };
  }, [confirm]);

  return <>{confirm ? "true" : "false"}</>;
};

export default App;
```

React version: 17.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it's because you're passing an empty dependencies array to the useEffect inside the useKeypress function; this way, the event listener has always the same callback.

The easiest change would be to pass the dependencies, for example:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export function useKeypress(key, action, deps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function onKeyup(e) {
      if (e.key === key) action();
    }
    window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyup);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keyup", onKeyup);
  }, deps);
}

const App = () => {
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);

  // this function never run
  const secPress = () => {
    console.log("Double escape pressed");
  };

  const _confirm = useCallback(() => {
    setConfirm(prev => !prev);
    console.log(confirm); // <-- always show false
    if (confirm) {
      secPress();
    }
  }, [confirm]);

  useKeypress("Escape", _confirm, [confirm]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const d = setTimeout(() => {
      setConfirm(false);
    }, 5000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(d);
    };
  }, [confirm]);

  return <>{confirm ? "true" : "false"}</>;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer is incorrect, you shouldn't have to add [confirm] to the event listener effect

working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/00rxv

```
  const [stage, setStage] = useState("initial");

  const secPress = () => {
    console.log("Double escape pressed");
  };

  const keydown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
      setStage((current) => (current === "initial" ? "confirm" : "success"));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keydown);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", keydown);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stage === "success") {
      secPress();
    }
    if (stage !== "confirm") {
      return;
    }

    const d = setTimeout(() => {
      setStage("initial");
    }, 2000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(d);
    };
  }, [stage]);
```

Comment: 1) You're not explaining in any way why my answer is incorrect in your opinion
2) You realize you totally changed the code, right? It's not even working the same, since it blocks on "success"; that's not a behaviour requested in the question or present in the code provided.
3) try putting a console.log after your setStage invocation, you'll have the same issue of the OP.